# Monster AI in Erlang - how to tick the Process, how to read Player's Health

Tags: erlang

Trying to wrap my head around Erlang's processes, here are two questions regarding a game server:

**First Question:** A Monster should randomly move around every x seconds if Idle. Whats the proper way to update or tick a process every x seconds? What's the most elegant way to do this?

**Second Question:** A Monster wants to attack a player, but wants to check its position first. The common way is:

```
if dist(mob_pos, player_pos) < 10 then send attack message to player
```

I know that I can check the player's pos by sending it a 'ask-for-pos' message and reading the result in the next update. But here is the problem: its the next update, and the monster wouldn't know that it just asked for the pos to attack the player. What's the Erlang way to check the position and then send an attack message to the player afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First Question: A Monster should randomly move around every x seconds
>   if Idle. Whats the proper way to update or tick a process every x
>   seconds? What's the most elegant way to do this?

If you use receive/after clause, an erlang process will be awaken to execute this **"after"**

block of code. This is the most efficient way to do what you want:

```
receive
  msg_a -> ...;
  mg_b -> ...;
  ...
  after <milliseconds> ->
     do_whatever you have to
end.
```

The erlang VM can't skip "after" block of code. Also, as "after" block of code is not a message from mailbox, you can't lose it. And it's guaranteed that it will be executed.

But if you use this scheme, your monsters will be independent actors. 
For example.  Monster1 has born. Then he sleeps for 10000 milliseconds. In a second another monster borns - he sleeps for 10000 millisecond. So the Monster1 will be awaken for a second when the second monster will be sleeping for a second yet.

In real world everything happens like I described above, though:) 
Biological time ticks for each person independently. But **physical** time ticks simultaneously for all objects.

So it depends which time you want to use - biological or physical(in terms of gameplay)
Erlang suits more for biological. But physical may be implemented using synchronization.

> Second Question: A Monster wants to attack a player, but wants to
>   check its position first. The common way is:
>   if dist(mob_pos, player_pos) < 10 then send attack message to player I
>   know that I can check the player's pos by sending it a 'ask-for-pos'
>   message and reading the result in the next update. But here is the
>   problem: its the next update, and the monster wouldn't know that it
>   just asked for the pos to attack the player. What's the Erlang way to
>   check the position and then send an attack message to the player
>   afterwards?

It's a design flaw of your system.
Does a robber ask you for your position or whatever when he wants to rob you? :)))

**There should be a "game" process. This process should**

1. Only if you use "physical time",  in "after" clause send synchronous(call <--> handle_call) "time tick" messages to all game objects. And they will do whatever they need on "time ticks"
2. This game process should observer all positions of objects. It may be even not one and only process, it may be a supervision tree, though. Like, a "game" object asks a robber on a time tick 10 seconds from now: "where are you", he answers "I'm at pos (x,y,z)", then "game" asks a creature to be robbed "guy, and where are you?". This loosely creature answers: "I'm at position (x1,y1,z1)" And if all communication lays within acceptable boundaries and if distance calculated by "game" object between a creature to be robbed and a robber lays within robbable boundaries - the robber robbs.(a "game" sends him a message "rob").

   You can think about a "game" object like about a some kind of God.

This was just one approach. A synchronous one.

**But you can implement another approach/design. An asynchronous one**, like in common relativity problem :) Be an Enstein :) When a robber doesn't "ask" about a position of a victim. But he "sees" the position of a victim if he can.

In this case there should be a "light" object/process which would tell if an another object can be seen out of here.

For example, a receptors(eyes) of a robber are in "accept" state. And all "light beam" processes transfer the info about nearby terrain to a robber.

To do this, you should bind an erlang process to each cell. And each cell should be allowed to pass messages ONLY to nearby cells. If you, say, use 6-side cells like in civilization 5, there would be 6 nearby cells. This way you can even simulate "local time for matter" like in 
 [Enstein's works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity).

This is another, more complex architecture. I won't be explaining it here, cauze it will take much much more letters and pages :)

I gave you an idea, 2 concepts. You can push them forward using erlang. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

for question 1:
there is a nice timer module in the standard library:
http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html
This can give you the tick for your application.

for question 2:
it seems like you wonder about synchronisation between the monster and the player. 
If you go for asynchronous messaging between the player and the monster, it is possible that between the question and the reponse a tick arrive from the timer (very unlikely though).
What you could do is to make a synchronous call instead that will block the processes until the action is solved.

You can model both monster and player as gen_server and use their cast (asynchronous) and call (synchronous) method. See:
http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html